# Choropleth map slider only showing the first year , and not including other steps - no error provided

Tags: python, plotly

I've been working on trying to create a choropleth map with a date slider, and while the map and initial year of data is output, when the slider is moved past the initial year, the map goes white and the 'range' indicator on the right side noting the number of 'Total Deaths' disappears.

[image: First Year]

[image: Other years]

I receive no error, and am not sure what could be happening, any help would be great. Thanks!

The [Kaggle dataset link](https://www.kaggle.com/pavan9065/air-pollution)

The code

```
df_total = pd.read_csv('../input/air-pollution/death-rates-total-air-pollution.csv')

scl = [[0.0, '#ffffff'],[0.2, '#ff9999'],[0.4, '#ff4d4d'],
       [0.6, '#ff1a1a'],[0.8, '#cc0000'],[1.0, '#4d0000']]

data_slider = []


for year in df_total.Year.unique():


    # I select the year (and remove DC for now)
    dff = df_total[(df_total['Year']== year )]
    dff = df_total = dff.rename(columns={"Deaths - Air pollution - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)":"Total Deaths"})
   
    for col in dff.columns:  # I transform the columns into string type so I can:
        dff[col] = dff[col].astype(str)

    ### I create the text for mouse-hover for each state, for the current year    
    '''dff['Total Deaths'] = dff['Entity'] '''

    ### create the dictionary with the data for the current year
    data_one_year = dict(
                        type='choropleth',
                        locations = dff['Entity'],
                        z=dff['Total Deaths'].astype(float),
                        locationmode='country names',
                        colorscale = scl,
                        text = dff['Entity'],
                        )

    data_slider.append(data_one_year)  # I add the dictionary to the list of dictionaries for the slider
    
    steps = []

for i in range(len(data_slider)):
    step = dict(method='restyle',
                args=['visible', [False] * len(data_slider)],
                label='Year {}'.format(i + 1990)) # label to be displayed for each step (year)
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)
    
sliders = [dict(active=0, pad={"t": 1}, steps=steps)]  


layout = dict(geo=dict(scope='world',
                       projection={'type': 'equirectangular'}),
              sliders=sliders)

#create the figure object:

fig = dict(data=data_slider, layout=layout) 

#plot in the notebook

plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematic inside for loop:

```
 dff = df_total = dff.rename(
        columns={"Deaths - Air pollution - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)": "Total Deaths"})
```

Replace it with:

```
 dff = dff.rename(
        columns={"Deaths - Air pollution - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)": "Total Deaths"})
```